# Reusing git branch names

Tags: git, branch, reusability

I am wondering what happens if I create a branch in git that have the same name as a remote branch. Would the first branch stop to exist in the remote repository once I push my branch? For example, lets say I clone the following bare repository

```
master    A----B---C
                \
mybranch         D---E
```

then I proceed to create a branch called *mybranch* from the *master* and generate a few commits. I know that if I checkout mybranch a tracking branch will be created but if I create a branch (*git branch mybranch*) what would happen once I decide to push *mybranch*? I did a few examples but I couldn't figure out what was happening. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried pushing the branch to remote?

Answer (score 1):

So in your particular example you'd create a commit F based on commit C and have a local branch *mybranch* point to that commit, creating the following situation:

```
mybranch                    F
                           /
master           A----B---C
                       \
origin/mybranch         D---E
```

If you'd try to push that branch/commit to *mybranch* on the upstream, Git would refuse the push since it would be a non fast-forward update of *mybranch*.

The fact that your local branch happens to have the same name as the upstream branch does not come into play here. The upstream Git doesn't care or know about your local branch names (if there even is a name; what's being pushed could be a nameless detached head).

Comment: I completed the example again and I certainly got a warning from git. Great! Not sure what happened the first time I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

"TL;DR" summary: it really does work, but it can confuse *you*, so you probably should re-arrange your branch names at some point.  Below is a much expanded version of [Magnus Bäck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21193958/1256452).

---

There are two entities involved here (or more if you have more than one remote, but let's stick with two :-) , yours and `origin`):

- your own repo, and
- "the" remote.

Having an ambiguous *`refname`* (see [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)) *only* affects "your own repo", because the remote has its own names, in its own `.git` directory.  Moreover, when you type in a *`refname`* and make your git commands resolve it, it's resolved according to those rules listed in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).<sup>1</sup>

This is still not a great situation, because it can confuse the heck out of *you*.  Also, "only affects you" is maybe an exaggeration or a "white lie", because when you use `git push`, there are a lot of options:

- You can `git push origin mybranch:newbranch`.  This tells your git to look up the name `mybranch` (with the usual resolving, which gets commit `F` in [Magnus Bäck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21193958/1256452)), and then contact `origin` and ask it to update or even create a branch on its side named `newbranch`.
- You can `git push origin mybranch`.  This tells your git to look up the name `mybranch` as usual, but then contact `origin` and ask it to update or create a branch on its side named `mybranch`, which (as already noted) would not be a fast-forward and would get refused.
- You can `git push` or `git push origin`, which looks up your `push.default` setting.<sup>2</sup>
  If that's set to `current`, `matching`, or `simple`, git really wants your name to match the remote's name.  If it's set to `nothing`, git demands that you supply the "other side name" every time.  If it's set to `upstream`, git uses the "upstream" name,<sup>3</sup> which is not required to match the local name.

Thus, the `push.default` setting of `upstream` is pretty much meant for this kind of situation: not necessarily an *ambiguous* name, but any case where your name, `mybranch`, differs from the name on the remote, `newbranch`.

(There's also the question of what happens with `git fetch`.  See extra info below footnote 3.)

---

<sup>1</sup>For historical reasons, or maybe just to be obnoxious, the `git checkout` command resolves branch names with different rules.  I don't actually know why, but we're kind of stuck with it, at least for the foreseeable future.

<sup>2</sup>Settings are set/changed/examined with [`git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).  The `push` command also checks `remote.origin.push`, if that's set, and even `branch.mybranch.pushremote`, if *that*'s set.  This gets terribly confusing if you configure a lot of configuration settings!  Let's assume you don't configure yourself into weird corners here.

<sup>3</sup>The "upstream" is found by combining `branch.name.remote` and `branch.name.merge`.  For instance, you can set `branch.mybranch.remote` to `origin` and `branch.mybranch.merge` to `newbranch`.  Then the "upstream" name for `mybranch` is `origin/newbranch`.  Thus, the `upstream` setting for `push.default` lets `git push` automatically work out that `mybranch` pushes to `newbranch` on remote `origin`.  This same "upstream" configuration works automatically with `git fetch`.

Because there are two entities involved, when `git fetch` brings over `origin`'s branch names, it needs to separate them out from your own branch names.  The way it does this is to grab all the branch names from the remote repo, and then insert text in front of them: branch `master` on remote `origin` becomes local ref-name `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  **Your** branches go in `refs/heads/name`; **their** branches go in `refs/remotes/origin/name`; and these two name-spaces are guaranteed not to collide, because `heads/` and `remotes/` are different.

There's a configuration entry—don't change this particular one unless you know what you are doing; it's really just there so that mirrors can work differently—that says:

```
remote.origin.fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

that does this.  That's how `mybranch` on `origin` becomes `origin/mybranch` in the first place, and when you enter the name `origin/mybranch`, again because of the rules in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), that translates into the full, never-ambiguous name `refs/remotes/origin/mybranch`, which then names the desired commit.